# Kubernetes liveness probe

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

How can I write kubernetes readiness probe for my spring boot application, which takes around 20 second to startup ? I tried to follow example from [Configure Liveness, Readiness and Startup Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/), but I'm not sure how does Kubernetes figure out status code 200 as success

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: backend
    name: liveness-http
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/liveness
    args:
    - /server
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
        httpHeaders:
        - name: Custom-Header
          value: Awesome
      initialDelaySeconds: 3
      periodSeconds: 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kubernetes kubelet will make a http request at `/healthz` path in your application and expects http status code 200 returned from that endpoint for the probe to be successful. So you need to have a rest endpoint in a rest controller which will return 200 from `/healthz`. An easy way to achieve it would be to include spring boot actuator dependency and change the liveness probe path to `/actuator/health/liveness`. Spring boot actuator by default comes with a rest controller endpoint which returns 200 from `/actuator/health/liveness`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-kubernetes-probes

Answer (score 3):

`initialDelaySeconds` field tells the kubelet that it should wait 20 seconds before performing the first probe. So this is generally configured to the value/time that the container / pod takes to start.

Configure `initialDelaySeconds: 20` with the value as 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

K8 engine considers response code 200-399 as a successful probe. In your case you can add initial delay seconds for your probe to start with a delay of 20 seconds.